# Efficient modular right shift

Tags: math, optimization, greatest-common-divisor, modular-arithmetic

Given an odd modulus `m`, one can compute `a/2^k mod m` by finding the modular inverse `i` of `2^k` and then compute `a*i mod m`.

Is there a better way to perform a modular right shift? Is it possible to avoid computing `i`? What if `m` was prime? What if `k` was one?

Comment: You might find more attention if you can decide on a programming language for which you want to discuss that and use a  corresponding tag.

Comment: AFAIK, no, computing the inverse is the fastest method (there are some trick you can do by hand to speed this up but this should not change the complexity in the end). Note that if `m` is small, then you can pre-compute the values and do this operation very quickly.

Comment: The modular inverse of 2 is easy to compute, it's (m+1)/2. That can be done with an actual right shift. So a*(2^(-k)) mod m = a*(Z^k) mod m, where Z = (m+1) >> 1 (as an integer), assuming all values are non-negative integers. No need for the extended euclidean algorithm.